# Problema al intentar pasar el valor del input a la URL de la API

Tags: javascript, api, input, fetch

El problema es que al intentar pasar el valor del input a la URL de la API no la "reconoce", quisiera saber si hay alguna solución, adjunto mi código:

```
const pokeInput = document.getElementById('input').value
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
const dataBox = document.getElementById('dataBox')
const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeInput}`


fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    //Evento click, que en teoria deberia pasar por consola los datos del fetch
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  })
```

Comment: que es exactamente lo que no reconoce la url o el valor del input o el html del input o el api?

Comment: estoy casi seguro que el problema es el orden en el que intentas hacer las cosas ...

Answer (score 1):

basado en un hipotetico html con un campo y un boton con los datos que indicas; el problema radica en el orden y donde capturas el valor en el load del documento... no es lo adecuado, ya que el valor en el load es vacio (nulo), incluso cuando modificas y das el click sigue siendo vacio (nulo); en este caso lo combeniente seria inclur la captura del valor en el momento en que das el click:

***Ejemplo:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fetch API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa un nombre de Pokemon">
    <button id="btn">Buscar Pokemon</button>
    <div id="dataBox"></div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
        const dataBox = document.getElementById('dataBox')

        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const pokeInput = document.getElementById('input').value
          const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeInput}`

          fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data)
              dataBox.textContent = JSON.stringify(data)
            })
        })
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

como podras ver estoy usando [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) y pase la captura de `pokeInput` dentro del evento, el resultado lo podras ver en `dataBox`

Answer (score 0):

##### Primer error:

Está mal estructurado tu código, no puedes tener un `eventListener` dentro del `fetch`, más bien, el `eventListener` debe encerrar al `fetch` para indicar que cuando hagamos clic en el botón, ocurra las instrucciones de adentro (el `fetch`), así que, esto:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log(data) })
  })
```

Debería ser así:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { console.log(data) })
})
```

---

##### Segundo error:

Ahora, dentro del `eventListener` se debería de capturar el valor de tu input, ya que, al tenerlo afuera, indicamos que capturamos el valor del input cuando cargue la página, y ese valor siempre será `null` porque al cargar la página el valor del input es **vacío**. Lo que hice fue capturar el valor del input dentro del `eventListener` y concatenar ese valor con la URL, quedando así:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const pokeInput = document.getElementById('input').value // cada vez que ocurra el listener, capturo el valor del input...
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeInput}` // y lo concateno con la URL.
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { console.log(data) })
})
```

---

##### Código completo:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn') // capturo al botón...

// y cuando haga clic al botón, entro al listener...
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const pokeInput = document.getElementById('input').value // capturo el valor del input...
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeInput}` // y lo concateno con la URL...
  console.log("Valor de mi input =>", pokeInput)
  fetch(url) // luego, hago fetch a esa URL...
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { console.log(data) }) // y muestro en consola la data que me trae el fetch.
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="pikachu">
<button id="btn">Buscar</button>
```

Comment: chame gusta mas tu respyesta que la mia

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 jeje, le doy +1, también me parece buena :-)